# Selecting and deselecting reclerview item not changing image properly

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview

I am working on a bus booking app. I want when i select seat it will change seat image. and deselecting it should change to last image. My other functionalities working fine of selecting seat and showing seat no. in textview and deselect also working fine. But it just not changing seat image is the problem. If i click on seat no. 18 i.e actually 20th it change image of 1st seat i.e seat no A. if seat 19 then B, if seat 20 then seat no. 1 and so on.

[image: See here i selected seat no 18 and it changes icon of first]

```
public class SeatSelection extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

RecyclerView recyclerView;
SeatAdapter seatAdapter;
List<SeatDetails> seatDetailsList;
List seatNo;
TextView txtSeatNo;
TextView fare;
public Bitmap seatIcon;
public Bitmap seatSelect;
String cost;
int amt;
int charge;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seat_selection);

    seatIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seat_layout_screen_nor_avl);
    seatSelect = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seat_layout_screen_nor_std);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 5);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    seatAdapter = new SeatAdapter(this, loadBustListSeats());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(seatAdapter);


}

public class SeatDetails {
    String name;
    boolean isBlank;
    boolean isSelected;

    public SeatDetails(String name, boolean isBlank, boolean isSelected) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isBlank = isBlank;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}

public List<SeatDetails> loadBustListSeats() {
    seatDetailsList = new ArrayList<SeatDetails>();
    int seatSerialNumber = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        if (isBlankSeat(i)) {
            seatDetailsList.add(new SeatDetails("", true, false));
        } else {
            if (i == 0) {
                seatDetailsList.add(new SeatDetails("A", true, false));
            } else if (i == 1) {
                seatDetailsList.add(new SeatDetails("B", true, false));
            } else {
                seatDetailsList.add(new SeatDetails(String.valueOf(seatSerialNumber), true, false));
                seatSerialNumber = seatSerialNumber + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return seatDetailsList;
}


public boolean isBlankSeat(int i) {
    if ((60 - (i - 1)) < 5)
        return false;
    else
        return i % 5 == 2 ;
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


}

public void seatSelected(int pos)
{
    charge = charge + amt;
    seatNo.add(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName());
    txtSeatNo.setText(seatNo.toString());
    fare.setText(String.valueOf(charge));

    seatDetailsList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
    seatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void seatDeselected(int pos)
{
    charge = charge - amt;
    fare.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
    seatNo.remove(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName());
    txtSeatNo.setText(seatNo.toString());
    seatDetailsList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
    seatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public class SeatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


    class ViewHolderOriginal extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        ViewHolderOriginal(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);

        }
    }

    class ViewHolderBlank extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ViewHolderBlank(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }

    }


    public   Context cntx;
    public SeatAdapter(Context context, List<SeatDetails> list){
        cntx = context;
        seatDetailsList = list;
    }

    // 0= Original view 1= Blank View
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if((getItemCount()-(position-1))<5)
            return 0;
        else
            return position % 5 == 2 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 60;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (viewType == 1)
            return new ViewHolderBlank(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_blank, parent, false));
        else
            return new ViewHolderOriginal(inflater.inflate(R.layout.seatrow_grid, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ViewHolderBlank) {

        } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderOriginal) {
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsList.get(position);

                    if (seatDetails.isSelected){
                        seatDeselected(position);
                        ((ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(seatIcon);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        seatSelected(position);
                        ((ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(seatSelect);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderBlank) {

    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderOriginal) {
        SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsList.get(position);
        if (seatDetails.isSelected){
            ((ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(seatSelect);
        }else{
            ((ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(seatIcon);
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsList.get(position);

                if (seatDetails.isSelected){
                    seatDeselected(position);
                }else{
                    seatSelected(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You forgot to setup the view according to data. As you have notifyDataSetChanged() in your functions, no need to change image in onClcik(). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the list when user select/deselect seat. So you can use notifydatasetchanged() for refresh the list after event.

Comment: i am already doing in seatSelected and seatDeselected function